# macro execution with i-search fails under Linux and succeeds under windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, linux, keyboard-macros

Imagine you've got file with FirstName|LastName| like this :

```
John|toto|
Hanz|titi|
```

and want to put the first names at the end of the lines (just an stupid exemple). You may use Macro Recordind for that and type:

> Arrow-down Home Ctrl-Space Ctrl-s | RET Arrow-left Ctrl-C End Ctrl-v

Under Linux, the execution of the macro rings the bell, hence doesn't work. But under Windows it works fine ! Isn't that a shame ? :)
If we look at the macro definitions, the results are just a very litlle bit different. Under Linux:

```
(fset 'makeMail2
      (lambda (&optional arg)
        "Keyboard macro."
        (interactive "p")
        (kmacro-exec-ring-item
          '([down home 67108896 19 124 return left 3 3 timeout end 22]
            0
            "%d")
          arg)))`
```

And under Windows :

```
(fset 'makeMail2Win
      (lambda (&optional arg)
        "Keyboard macro."
        (interactive "p")
        (kmacro-exec-ring-item
          '([down home 67108896 19 124 return left 3 timeout end 22]
            0
            "%d")
          arg)))
```

The only difference I see is `left 3 3` versus `left 3` under Windows.
Is this the cause of the fail ? Is this a bug or is it normal ? How can I make my macro work under Linux ?

NB: Linux Emacs version is 25, and Windows is 24...

Comment: "Linux Emacs version is 25, and Windows is 24" seems like it would be more significant than the platform.  Can you please test with the same version of [Emacs 25 on Windows](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-25/)?"

Comment: Other observations: `3` is `C-c`, so `3 3` is `C-c C-c` which is a commonly-used key sequence in various Emacs modes and keymaps. You're obviously *expecting* `cua-mode` to be in effect, as you're trying to use `C-c` and `C-v` for copy and paste.  Is that assumption actually correct in your Linux case?

Comment: @phils I've just tested with Emacs25 on Windows and the results are the same. But I've realized yesterday that makeMail2Win was working fine on Linux ! So the problem comes from the definition of the macro on Linux. Guess what I did : I just modified makeMail2 by suppressing one of the two 3 and, bingo, it workes fine under Linux. Yes, I use cua-mode on both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **don't use cua-mode on Linux, it's OK if you are on windows (but not on wsl of course)**. It works fine when using `M-w` and `C-y` and the definition of the macro becomes:

```
(fset 'makeMailNoCua
   (lambda (&optional arg) 
   "Keyboard macro." 
   (interactive "p") 
   (kmacro-exec-ring-item 
      (quote ([down home 67108896 19 124 return left 134217847 end 25] 
      0 
      "%d"))
     arg)))
```

Many thanks to phils. Once the solution found, it's easier to find that the problem was known, see [Cua-mode and keyboard macros](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38780/cua-mode-and-keyboard-macros?rq=1) and has a fix ;)